# How to implement an "Apply" behavior in python

Tags: python

I'd like to implement an `apply()` behavior in a class instance.

by "Apply" i mean, typically realizing a parametric object in place. Meaning that the user might create a parametric object, change it's settings, and later on, realize the object.

Here is an example on how such an apply behavior would work in the context of a 3D application

```py
my_cube = ParametricCube()
my_cube.height = 2
my_cube.width = 1
my_cube.subdivision = 3

print(type(my_cube),) 
>>> <class ParametricCube>

#.. a few moments later

my_cube.make_real() #== apply in place behavior!

print(type(my_cube),) 
>>> <class 3D_Object>
```

The pythonic way to do it, would be to re-assign the variable
instead of using `my_cube.make_real()` we would use `my_cube = my_cube.make_real()`
i am not interested by this solution, we'd like to directly impact the value of `my_cube` w/o monkey patching many variable severywhere at runtime

Here is an abstract example, un-related to an 3D app context

```
class Expression():
    """parametric expression of a+b+c"""

    def __init__(self):
        #parameters defaults
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2
        self.c = 3

    def __str__(self):
        return str(f"<Expression '{self.a}+{self.b}+{self.c}'={self.a + self.b + self.c}>")

    def realize(self):
        """apply in place behavior"""

        #realize our expression into an int or float somehow?

        return None

x = Expression()
x.a = 1
x.b = 1
x.c = 1

print(x) 
>>>"<Expression 1+1+1=3>"

print(type(x))
>>> <class Expression>

#apply in place behavior
x.realize()

print(x) 
>>>3

print(type(x))
>>> <class 'float'>
```

Comment: I’m not entirely sure what you are asking for but I think you might be looking for the [factory pattern](https://realpython.com/factory-method-python/).

Comment: Assuming you have supplied a simplified example: After the parametric object has been *realized* will it retain all of its original attributes and gain the attributes of the new type OR will its attributes be wholly replaced with the attributes of the new type??

Comment: `..directly impact the reference of my_cube..` - you really need to expand on this in your question. This sounds like you want to manipulate the locals or globals dictionary of the current scope and have the name `my_cube` be associated with a completely different object and have this *realized* when the method is executed. Do you want to do this because at runtime you will have no idea what *name* the parametric object has been assigned to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what are you asking for, but what about this?

```
class Realized:
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.a + self.b + self.c)


class Expression:
    """a+b+c parametric expression"""

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2
        self.c = 3

    def __str__(self):
        return str(
            f"<Expression '{self.a}+{self.b}+{self.c}'={self.a + self.b + self.c}>"
        )

    def realize(self):
        """apply in place behavior"""

        # how to apply self into ??
        temp = self
        self.__class__ = Realized  # Change the type of the object
        self.__dict__.update(temp.__dict__)  # Copy over data

        return None


x = Expression()
x.a = 1
x.b = 1
x.c = 1

print(x)

print(type(x))

x.realize()  # apply in place behavior

print(x)
print(type(x))
```

Output:

$ python test.py

```
<Expression '1+1+1'=3>
<class '__main__.Expression'>
3
<class '__main__.Realized'>
```

---

Here's an extendable implementation:

```py
from typing import Any


class Realizable:
    """Inherit this to have a class that can be realized"""

    """Private var to hold class type to be realized"""
    _realize_class_type: Any

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._realize_class_type = kwargs["realizer"]

    def realize(self):
        """apply in place behavior"""

        temp = self
        self.__class__ = self._realize_class_type  # Change the type of the object
        self.__dict__.update(temp.__dict__)  # Copy over data


class ExpressionRealized:
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.a + self.b + self.c)


class Expression(Realizable):
    """a+b+c parametric expression"""

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2
        self.c = 3

    def __str__(self):
        return str(
            f"<Expression '{self.a}+{self.b}+{self.c}'={self.a + self.b + self.c}>"
        )


x = Expression(realizer=ExpressionRealized)
x.a = 1
x.b = 1
x.c = 1

print(x)

print(type(x))

x.realize()  # apply in place behavior

print(x)
print(type(x))
```

Comment: brilliant! can we for example apply our `Expression` into a `float` that way, as the initial example suggested?

Comment: @DB3D So you would like to return a plain `float` object after calling `realize()`?

Comment: I am wondering if instead of using another man-made class, we could apply the Expression into python base type, such as `int`  `float` or `str` for example, so in your first solution using `self.__class__ = float` instead of `self.__class__ = Realized`, unfortunately it is not supported by python, and i also need to implement this behavior

Comment: Ya unfortunately. I couldn’t find a way to implement that too. You can override the `__float__` method in the realizer class, but you will need to type cast it later and that goes back to your initial problem.